# Problem with using a form validator in Flutter (dart)

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I was trying to implement a login form in flutter watching this video (minute 20:00) (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GFKqoIAPd0Q) and everything went great until this part:

```html
class InputText extends StatelessWidget {
  final String label;
  final String hint;
  final Icon icono;
  final TextInputType keyboard;
  final bool obsecure;
  final void Function(String data) onChanged;
  final String Function(String data) validator;
  const InputText({ Key? key, 
      this.label = '',
      this.hint = '',
      required this.icono,
      this.keyboard = TextInputType.text,
      this.obsecure = false,
      required this.onChanged,
      required this.validator}) 
       : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: TextFormField(
        keyboardType: this.keyboard,
        obscureText: this.obsecure,
        onChanged: this.onChanged,
        validator: validator,                      // THIS LINE RIGHT HERE
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: this.hint,
          labelText: this.label,
          labelStyle: TextStyle(
```

The validator there gives an error, but in the video it worked fine.
I'm currently working with Flutter version 2.10.3 and Dart SDK version 2.16.1.
Does anyone know how to solve this? Thanks in advance

Comment: can you add the `validator` code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change declaration of the `validator` to:

```
final String? Function(String? data) validator;
```

Comment: Further if validator can be null then you can use this declaration:
final String? Function(String? data)? validator;